# it is possible create a web page using tags from html5 with intraweb?

Tags: html, intraweb

I'm working with delphi xe2 in an application in which I am using intraweb, but my question is whether it is possible to make a website using tags from html5, I read in various forums that it is possible but I still have not managed to make that my html file display the css3 styles.

For example I have this simple code in my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li>Telefono</li>
            <li>Correo Electronico</li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>INICIO</li>
            <li>DEPARTAMENTOS
                <ul>
                    <li>Ninos</li>
                    <li>Caballeros</li>
                </ul>               
            </li>
            <li>CATEGORIAS
               <ul>
                   <li>telefonos</li>
                   <li>Herramientas</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>INFORMACION DE CONTACTO</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

And in my Css3 file this

```
header {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F0E9;
}

ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

ul li {
   font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: -4px;
   position: relative;
   padding: 15px 20px;
   background: #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

...and the result is nothing, I thank you in advance for the help

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your HTML and CSS. If you're not seeing anything then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Just to make sure, since you're asking about HTML5 tags, what you're saying is that if you replace `<header>` and `<nav>` with something like divs, it works as expected?

Comment: Yes, it is correct if I put some tags like <div> works perfectly

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Only in IE 9 and Chrome

Comment: Created a fiddle: everything seems working?
https://jsfiddle.net/y8Lcz67h/

Comment: everything working fine Danny van Holten thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup and CSS work fine for me.  If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you can use one of their debugging tools like "element inspector", to see where the problem is lying, but your html and css do work and create a navbar as intended.

Comment: Thanks, I could find the problem, I uninstalled and reinstalled chrome and now everything works perfectly, so I see IE9 does not support some html5 tags, so that the application is compatible with chrome, and Goran Kostadinovic than previously showed you was just a piece of code in my application.

Comment: Internet Explorer will all ways be a challenge for web developers. Have you looked at Bootstrap.  It has many components you can use including navbars.  You can overwrite their defaults by placing the link to your CSS below the others -- .http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/  also check out the components section -- http://getbootstrap.com/components/